# What is this called in F# when a type appears after a specified type?

Tags: f#

I have seen examples like this:

```
 type OptionalString = string option 
 type customers = customer list
```

In these example both option and list type appears after string and customer types.

1. Is there documentation that I can find that shows all the list of types that can be written like this?
2. Also is this similar to <> in c#?

Comment: OptionalString is either a string or null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described in the [specification [pdf]](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf):

**5.1.1 Named Types**

> Named types have several forms, as listed in the following table
>
> *type long-ident* Named type with one type argument; processed the same
>   as long-ident<type>

so you can use this form for generic types with a single parameter. This works for user-defined types e.g.

```
type Test<'a> = Test of 'a
let x : int Test = Test(3)
```